# How to remove decimal separator from float in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm reading a csv into a dataframe and I need to get rid of the decimal separators.

```
0      24.860
1       8.132
2       8.119
3       6.417
4       8.109
5      14.503
6       8.037
7       8.367
8       8.299
9      13.887
10     40.620
11     40.868
12      8.203
13     12.602
14      8.366
15      6.293
16      8.441
17      6.272
18      3.404
19     12.309
20      5.888
```

I tried:

```
df['energyConsumptionInKWh'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\.',"", regex=True)
df['energyConsumptionInKWh'].astype(str).str.replace('.','')
```

But the results are wrong:

```
0                     2486
1                     8132
2                     8119
3         6417000000000001
4                     8109
5                    14503
6                     8037
7                     8367
8                     8299
9                    13887
10                    4062
11                   40868
12                    8203
13                   12602
14                    8366
15        6292999999999999
16                    8441
17                    6272
18                    3404
19       12309000000000001
20                    5888
```

I also tried:

```
pd.read_csv('.....csv',sep=';', thousands='.', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

As well wrong results, and this solution is not goog because there are other values in the csv where I need the decimal separators.

```
0       2486
1       8132
2       8119
3       6417
4       8109
5      14503
6       8037
7       8367
8       8299
9      13887
10      4062
11     40868
12      8203
13     12602
14      8366
15      6293
16      8441
17      6272
18      3404
19     12309
20      5888
```

What can I do to get the right results? e.g. `24.860 = 24860, 8.132 = 8132`

Comment: `24.860 * 1000`  gives `24860`

Comment: I try your example at my pc. `pd.read_csv(filname, delimiter=' ', thousands='.')` works. 24.860 became 24860

Comment: is it `decimals` or `thousands` separator?

Comment: *1000 = 24860.0 in dataframe.

Comment: so it was `decimals`, not `thousands` separator

Comment: try this one: `pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=' ', thousands='.', decimal=',')`. Set your own delimiter

Comment: if you want `24860` instead of `24860.0` then convert to integers `df["energyConsumptionInKWh"].astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
df['energyConsumptionInKWh'] = (df['energyConsumptionInKWh'] * 1000).astype(int).astype(str).str.replace('.','')
```